# Virtualmin Restore from Backup

Tags: linux, backup, restore

I had to re install my VPS due to some fatal problems, it now has a clean version of ubuntu 8.04 and virtualmin. I have 18 domains that i have backed up on my home computer which i spent 3 hours uploading these files to the server so i could do a restore with them.

But when i restore using the Virtualmin restore panel i get this error:

---

Starting restore of 18 domains from local file /restore ..

Extracting backup archive files ..
.. done

Backup does not contain virtual server information for missing domain homes/contact/.spamassassin/bayes.

### .. failed! See the progress output above for the reason why.

Also when i first installed virtualmin back on to this server i did get an installation error:

---

INFO - 2010-10-21 07:47:41 - Updating SpamAssassin rules...

### INFO - Rule updates failed

I don't know if it was that that is causing the problems.

Thanks, David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was to do with cross platform problems, when i re installed and used Ubuntu Server on both it works fine.